# Showing poster image when video ends using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im having a problem displaying my poster image after video ends. I have this code :

```
var video = document.getElementById('home_video');

video.addEventListener('click',function(){
video.currentTime = 0
video.play();
},false);
```

i understand you need to put a addEventListener 'ended' after to show the poster image but mine seems not to work. Is there and method i can use to show the poster image even after the video finished playing?

Comment: I find some Browsers have a problem with the `video` `poster` attribute. You may want to just change the background of an Element.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html